# HttpContex.Current.Profile showing username null

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, httpcontext, asp.net-profiles

I am using asp.net profile system. I created a model in mASP.NET MVC named CustomProfile.In this model i create 3 function CreateProfile(), SaveData(), LoadProfile().

I am calling LoadProfile() from logon action from AcountController but the problem is when i am using HttpContext.Current.Profile in LoadProfile() function it show username null. Whats the problem?

Comment: Is anonymous authentication enabled for your website in IIS?

Comment: Is the user authenticated before you call LoadProfile()?  It'd be a big help to see your code for those 3 functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows or Forms Authentication needs to be enabled on that Website/Web Application in IIS